# How would I fix the (Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples)

Tags: python, data-science

First here is the code

```
X=df[["SexA","Age","Fare","Pclass"]]


y = df[["Survived"]]

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
tnt = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =100)
```

So the error comes from the train_test_split() line. I've tried the .reshape method but it doesn't work. The X shape is (183,4) and the y_shape is (183,1).
Does this error have anything to do with the way I reference the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check your dimensions, they do not match. (X.shape[0] != y.shape[0])

The following code works fine

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.arange(183*4).reshape(183,4) # Shape: (183,4)
y = np.arange(183).reshape(183,1) # Shape: (183,1)

# This works
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I printed X.shape[0] and y.shape[0] and they were both 183.